# JBoss Pool datasource configuration - postgresql xa vs non-xa

Tags: postgresql, jboss, pool, xa

I'm reading the examples from here, and I found an interesting piece:

```
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresdb</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>admin</user-name>
      <password>admin</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
    </validation>
  </datasource>
  <drivers>
    <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
      <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
  </drivers>
</datasources>
```

It's not a `xa-datasource`, but the driver is declaring a `xa-datasource-class` apontando using `org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource`.

Why not use `org.postgresql.Driver`? What are the diferences? And why not use `driver-class` instead of `xa-datasource-class`?